# Print all platform devices

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How can I print all names of platform devices from platform_device list? I add support of omap-board in kernel, but have error likes it:

```
omap_uart.0: failed to claim resource 814
```

And probe of omap_serial isn't called, but of serial8250 is. I can't find problem.

Comment: By platform device, you mean a train?

Comment: Almost. http://lwn.net/Articles/448499/